# Firebase Firestore Android can't deserialize object

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to deserialize data from firebase firestore to a model (Foo)

```
data class Foo(
        var timestamp: Int = 0,
        var title: String = "",
        var question: String = "",
        var category: String = "",
        var content: String = "",
        var link: String = ""
) {
    fun Foo() {}
}
```

with query like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
                .orderBy(ORDER_KEY, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(LIMIT)
                .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
            snapshot.documents.forEach {
                println(it.data) // data print successfully
                // got error java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type com.google.firebase.firestore.Blob to int (found in field 'timestamp')
                val foo = it.toObject(Foo::class.java)
            }
        }
```

but got error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type com.google.firebase.firestore.Blob to int (found in field 'timestamp')`

I use firebase version `11.6.2` in my android project

where data in firestore is like in this screenshot:

[image]

Any idea why deserialization failed?

Comment: what does `println(it.data)` prints?

Comment: thank you after inspect printed data, I found one invalid data where `{timestamp=blob, title=blob, category=blob...}` when other data is normal ``{timestamp=1135129980, title=jkjk, category=xys..}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong datatype in your model class.

If your dataType is **timestamp** in firestore collection then use Date datatype to timestamp in your model currently you are using int.

in Java use this.

```
 public Date createdAt;
 public String createdBy;
```

For kotlin use this.

```
 val timestamp: Date? = null,
 var title: String = "",
 var question: String = "",
 var category: String = "",
 var content: String = "",
 var link: String = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
var timestamp: Blob
```

instead of :

```
var timestamp: Int = 0
```

Then you can use this method from Blob object:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Blob

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately it not working `Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type com.google.firebase.firestore.Blob to String (found in field 'timestamp')`

Comment: interesting, event if it is possible (not trying yet) how can I use blob as timestamp? I use number in firestore when storing the data

Comment: why don't you use integer on firestore?

Comment: if you input data manually in firebase console, the only option is number

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the Blog and Int variable types, but they did not work for Firebase's Timestamps.  Then, I used the following and it worked correctly:

```
import java.util.*
val timestamp: Date? =  null
```

I hope it works for you too.